# How do I find the differences between specific fields in two different MySQL TABLEs?

Tags: mysql

I get this data feed for a MySQL database. It will change, but there is no indication what has changed from the source. One approach to this, is create an OLD table and a NEW table. After the data feed has been populated to the NEW table, then do a comparison  of the OLD table and any reasons that don't exist in the OLD table, are considered new or changed records. By the way, there is no record ID from the data feed, so I can't use that as reference.

In MySQL, how do I compare the OLD table and the NEW table, on specific fields to get a list of those that are new or changed? Thanks!

Additional information update:
The data feed is a mailing list, but there is no assigned ID for the records from the source. So some of the fields from each record would have to been compared to find a match, but display those that are not a match. The purpose of this, is to produce a report for marketing of who the new customers are to be added, or if their information has been changed.

The focus on this task is to determine what records from the data feed are new or have been changed since the last feed. The feed is done nightly. There is no database that needs to be updated, we only need a report of what is new/changed since the last feed. The key field is Company_Name.

So I need to know how to do a MySQL query to search the old table (which was yesterday's data feed) and compare it to the new table. If the Company_name doesn't exist in the new table, then this would mean this customer has been deleted from the mailing list. If Company_name exists in the new table, but does not exist in the old table, this would indicate this is a new customer added to the mailing list.

Might this MySQL work to locate new records?

```
SELECT * FROM old
WHERE old.company_name
NOT IN (
SELECT new.company_name
FROM new
WHERE old.company_name=new.company_name
);
```

Comment: What is this "data feed"?  If records cannot be consistently identified, how can they be compared?

Comment: you can add a timestamp to know when the data's been updated. Why do you need to have two different tables and compare them? Explain the context, mainly about the 'datafeed' you're talking about.

Comment: What are the key fields/indexes on the table? As eggyal asked: How do you know whether you are inserting or updating? If you are always inserting, you'll get duplicate records, if you are updating, you have to know *what* you are updating... How do you know whether a record is new or changed? You have to compare it to the old record in some way...

Comment: (please see my reply above, I ran out of space here, thanks!)